# Vbscript hard validation

Tags: validation, vbscript

Hy I am new to programming vbscript.I am trying to make a textbox for user in which user has to enter file version(format 1,0,0,0).user must type one integer within commas.but I failed to make a validation script to do so.. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.I have been created this script to perform other kind of validation but I don't know how to do the validation for x,y,z,h format..

```
    Do
dtm = InputBox("Please Enter a Numeric File version using commas", _
            "File version")
Select Case True
    Case isNull(dtm), (not isNumeric(dtm)), dtm = "", dtm = empty, (dtm < 1 OR dtm > 9)
         MsgBox "Please enter between 1 and 9"
    Case else
        Exit do
End Select
Loop While True
'script on test pass
```

Comment: Post what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: I would `Split(dtm,",")` and compare each portion, use `Trim()`, `IsNumeric()` to ensure numbers.

Comment: I don't know how can u please paste it complete @Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job (have not tested with wscript/cscript), assuming accepted numbers are 0 to 9.

```
Function GetVersionNumber() As String
    Dim iParts, sVersion, oTmp, dtm

    iParts = 0
    sVersion = ""
    Do
        dtm = InputBox("Please Enter a Numeric File version using commas", "File version")
        For Each oTmp In Split(dtm, ",")
            If IsNumeric(Trim(oTmp)) Then
                If Len(sVersion) > 0 Then sVersion = sVersion & ","
                sVersion = sVersion & Trim(oTmp)
                iParts = iParts + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter between 0 and 9!" & vbCrLf & "You have typed " & oTmp
                iParts = 0 ' Reset to zero accepted parts
                sVersion = "" ' Reset to zero length string
            End If
        Next
    Loop Until iParts = 4 ' x,y,z,h format <- 4 parts
    GetVersionNumber = sVersion
End Function
```